# Adjusting the second y axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a ggplot graph I want to set limits to the y on the first axis but I have problem with the secondary axis vizualisation.

Here is what the code to generate the graph (inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716675/adjusting-the-second-y-axis-on-a-pareto-chart-in-r)):

```
mydata <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"), 
                    count = c(140, 90, 25, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6)) %>%
  mutate(cumsum=cumsum(count)) %>%
  mutate(cumperc=cumsum / sum(count) *100)
mydata$group <- factor(mydata$group, levels = mydata$group)

scaleRight <- tail(mydata$cumperc, n=1)/head(mydata$count, n=1)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x=group)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=count), fill='deepskyblue4', stat="identity") +
  geom_path(aes(y=cumperc/scaleRight, group=1),colour="orange", size=0.9) +
  geom_point(aes(y=cumperc/scaleRight, group=1),colour="orange") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*scaleRight, name = "Cumulative percent (%)", 
                                                           breaks=seq(0,100,10))) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 650)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.6),
        axis.text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold")) +
  labs( y="Number of person", x="group")
```

My problem is that the second axis is squished.

[image: plot output]

Any suggestion ?

Another thing, I would like to add an horizontal line base on the secondary axis (at 90%). 
I tried with `geom_hline` but it take the first axis into account.

Here is the graph I want to obtain (done in excel) 
[image]

Comment: why have you manually set y limits with `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 650))` ? Surely removing that would give your desired result?

Comment: Yes but I have another plot and I wanted to have the same limits between both for comparison purpose

Comment: So what's your expected output? Do you want the line plot to reach up to the top of the axis?

Comment: I have just edited my post to add expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just needed to adjust the scale adjustment in `scaleRight` to use the full y axis extent (up to 700 in your example) instead of just the range of data for the bars.

I've added the variable `ymax` to make it easy to change the range of data we want to extend our axis over.

The only other adjustment I made was to include `expand = expansion(mult = c(0,.05))` to replace `expand=c(0,0)` to add a 5% padding to the top of the axis as previously the top of the line was being cropped.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mydata <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"), 
                     count = c(140, 90, 25, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6)) %>%
  mutate(cumsum=cumsum(count)) %>%
  mutate(cumperc=cumsum / sum(count) *100)
mydata$group <- factor(mydata$group, levels = mydata$group)

ymax <- 700
scaleRight <- max(mydata$cumperc)/ymax

ggplot(mydata, aes(x=group)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=count), fill='deepskyblue4', stat="identity") +
  geom_path(aes(y=cumperc/scaleRight, group=1),colour="orange", size=0.9) +
  geom_point(aes(y=cumperc/scaleRight, group=1),colour="orange") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=90/scaleRight), linetype='dashed')+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0,.05)),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*scaleRight, name = "Cumulative percent (%)",
                                         breaks=seq(0,100,10))) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, ymax)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.6),
        axis.text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold")) +
  labs( y="Number of person", x="group")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>